# What is the state of the art in first order stochastic convex optimization?

Tags: randomized-algorithms, online-algorithms, stochastic-process, online-learning

- What is the optimally fastest convex risk minimizing algorithm which only uses a stochastic first order oracle? Is this SGD?
- What is the optimally fastest convex function minimizing algorithm which only uses a stochastic first order oracle?

  I think I can find 3 kinds of references :

  **If the objective is a finite sum of convex functions** then I think the optimally fastest algorithm is Allen-Zhu's *Katyusha* (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.05953.pdf)

  **But without this finite sum assumption and also without any smoothness assumption** I believe Shamir-Zhang's result  (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.1824.pdf) is optimal who showed that for strongly convex objectives and convex objectives the *function value* of the $T^{th}-$iterate is getting close in expectation to the global minima at rates $O(\frac {\log T}{ T})$ and $O(\frac {\log T}{ \sqrt{T}})$ respectively. They also show some averaging schemes which try to ameliorate the $\log T$ terms in the numerator.

  Upto this log factor I believe Shamir-Zhang is optimal given the lowerbounds in shown in, Hazan, E., Agarwal, A., and Kale, S. ``Logarithmic regret algorithms for online convex optimization" Machine Learning, 69(2-3):169–192, 2007.

  **If one is allowed smoothness and strong-convexity** then Lemma $1$ (page $4$) (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1109.5647.pdf) by Rakhlin-Shamir-Sridharan here  shows $O(\frac 1 T)$ convergence in expectation of the *squared distance from the global minima* of the $T^{th}-$iterate of the SGD for smooth strongly convex functions. (this also holds for the function value)

  This is optimal (reference?) and is also achievable for strongly convex functions by more complicated algorithms without needing smoothness like in Hazan, E. and Kale, S. ``Beyond the regret minimization barrier: An optimal algorithm for stochastic strongly-convex optimization" and this Rakhlin-Shamir-Sridharan paper shows that without smoothness SGD cant achieve this $O(\frac 1 T)$ rate.

  Did I miss any case?